# Lua loading screen - courotines vs C threads

Tags: c, multithreading, lua, coroutine

Right now i use similiar approach described here to load assets

http://www.lua.org/pil/9.4.html

Like

- Read file 1
- Render
- Read file 2
- Render
- ...

**Pro:** Using plain lua, simple.

**Contra:** it is not concurrent, every file read blocks render and only then goes to next one.
Also if you need to process data (e.g create a shader program from source, or decode picture and create texture) you need to pass it to C and take it back.

In the past i use C threads which calls lua function then they done loading file.

**Pro:** it is concurrent. You can process loaded data on C++ side

**Contra:** You need to pass loaded data back to Lua

Maybe i did quite wrong in both and there are better method for loading and processing data with Lua + C?

Comment: Is loading files concurrently faster enough to be worth the trouble?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go here with a **mixed** approach, using two types of threads:

- **Processings thread** that read from a message queue and do the actual loading of resources.
- **Loader threads** running Lua to processes the files asynchronously by enqueuing requests.

It can scale reasonably well by adding more threads of a specific type.

Of course, you should make sure it's really worth the hassle by profiling the current implementation. Using threads and message queues adds more C/C++ code. After all it's just a loading screen  ;)

Comment: I'd like to add that exchanging data between C and Lua is _fast_.